# Conflict between Windows and Android?

Tags: android, path, filesystems

Please help me solve this file path conflict:

As you know, many HTML pages use relative paths starting with a "/" for the href attribute of **link** tags. For example: `link href="/links/style.css"`.

In my code, I'm using [loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for a WebView to set a relative path name. If I give like this:

```
String webContent=//whole html page;
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///sdcard/mibook/pg90/",new String(webContent), "text/html", "UTF-8","" );
```

Result: No effect in WebView because (I felt) it takes two **'/'** while appending to pathname.

If I edit my HTML page by removing the first **"/"** from the href tag, then the WebView renders properly.

But my problem is that I don't want to edit HTML content as above. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javadoc of [`loadDataWithBaseURL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) states:

```
Note for post 1.0. Due to the change in the WebKit, the access to asset files through   
"file:///android_asset/" for the sub resources is more restricted. If you provide null 
or empty string as baseUrl, you won't be able to access asset files. If the baseUrl is
anything other than http(s)/ftp(s)/about/javascript as scheme, you can access asset 
files for sub resources
```

So basically only allowed URL for `file:///` scheme is `file:///android_asset/` where files are in your asset folder.

Comment: so i need to place my css files in asset folder?

Comment: if it only refers asset folder then why it is working for href=links/style.css and not for href=/links/style.css ? TIA

Comment: Because relative URLs with subdirectories must not have preceding slash: http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html